# Python. How to compare two texts excluding some blocks from comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, diff

Could you please help me to resolve the following task. My own solution is provided in answer below. I'm looking for the alternative approaches...

#### Task

We have two texts, for example, two Cisco router configs received with some time interval. How to determine are they the same and provide tools to review the differences.

Some blocks of texts should be excluded from comparison. For example, timestamp of last config's update on disk. Differences in such blocks should be ignored.

Also it is necessary to hide the sensitive data, contained in texts, like keys and passwords.

#### Example

These two texts should be automatically determined as equal (the same)

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 33530 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 23:58:33 EST Fri Nov 22 2019 by baz
! NVRAM config last updated at 00:32:38 EST Sat Nov 23 2019 by bar
!
version 15.3
service timestamps debug datetime msec localtime show-timezone year
service timestamps log datetime msec localtime show-timezone year
service password-encryption
no platform punt-keepalive disable-kernel-core
```

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 33530 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 10:00:00 EST Fri Dec  6 2019 by leo
! NVRAM config last updated at 10:00:05 EST Fri Dec  6 2019 by leo
! NVRAM config last updated at 10:12:25 EST Fri Dec  6 2019 by fix
!
version 15.3
service timestamps debug datetime msec localtime show-timezone year
service timestamps log datetime msec localtime show-timezone year
service password-encryption
no platform punt-keepalive disable-kernel-core
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I have edited my question. Could you please reconsider your opinion and help to open it again. The question has absolutely nothing to do with Code Review part of stack websites. Thanks

Comment: This is a special case of https://stackoverflow.com/q/32863329/2988730, but it's not an exact dupe. I'll vote to reopen

Comment: What is a password? What is volatile? The requirements aren't quite clear to me.

Comment: @JonasWilms, updated question for clarity

Comment: No, not really. Again: What is a password? What exactly are "some" things?

Comment: @JonasWilms, ok, nevermind.

Answer (score 2):

One of solutions is to normalize both texts, i.e. remove or replace with some characters the blocks of texts, which should be excluded from comparison.

In particular, for Cisco configs I use the following code:

```python
import re

_normalize_whiteout_config_regexes = tuple(map(lambda x: re.compile(x, re.MULTILINE), [
    # hide when and by whom was changed
    r'^! Last configuration change at (.+?) by (.+?)$',
    # Cisco Nexus - hide current time
    r'^!Time: (.+)$',
    # all - hide keys and passwords
    r' (?:password|secret|key) \d ([^\s]+)',
    r' (?:auth|priv) .*?0x([^\s]+)',
]))

_normalize_remove_config_regexes = tuple(map(lambda x: re.compile(x, re.MULTILINE), [
    # remove the whole line, because there could 0, 1 or 2 such lines
    r'(^! NVRAM config last updated at .+? by .+?\r?\n)',
    # Cisco Nexus - remove the whole line to be able comparing of
    # the running and startup configs
    r'(^!Startup config saved at: .+?\r?\n)',
    # all - remove part of command to be able comparing of
    # the running and startup configs
    r'show (running|startup)-config',
]))

def _normalize_match(_match, blackout_mode=True):
    """
    It blacks out or removes text in the matched groups.
    :param _match: match found by re.sub
    :param blackout_mode: Default: True
        True: all text characters in the matched groups will be replaced with '#'
        False: text in the matched groups will be removed
    """

    position = 0
    offset = _match.start()
    text = _match.group()
    _result = []
    for index in range(1, len(_match.groups()) + 1):
        start, end = _match.span(index)
        _result.append(text[position:start - offset])
        if blackout_mode:
            _result.append('#' * (end - start + 1))
        position = end - offset
    _result.append(text[position:])
    return ''.join(_result)


def cisco_normalize_config(out):

    # Hide volatile text parts
    for regex in _normalize_whiteout_config_regexes:
        out = regex.sub(_normalize_match, out)

    # Delete volatile text parts
    for regex in _normalize_remove_config_regexes:
        out = regex.sub(lambda x: _normalize_match(x, blackout_mode=False), out)

    return out


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("cisco_show_startup_config.txt") as f:
        _out = f.read()
    print(cisco_normalize_config(_out))
```

As a result, both example texts from question are normalized into the same text:

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 33530 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at ############################# by ####
!
version 15.3
service timestamps debug datetime msec localtime show-timezone year
service timestamps log datetime msec localtime show-timezone year
service password-encryption
no platform punt-keepalive disable-kernel-core
```

So the diff command won't find any differences.

We could use the existing Python and/or JavaScript diff solutions to display the differences found.